# Definition of Matrix Equivalence and Implications

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition, inverse

My understanding of the definition of matrix equivalence is that two matrices are equal if they can be transformed into each other by a combination of elementary row and column operations.

Therefore, if A = PB, where P is an invertible matrix composed of elementary matrices, then A and B are equivalent matrices because they can be transformed into each other by elementary row and column operations.

As such, A and B have equivalent reduced row echelon forms, and equivalent images and kernels, because A is equivalent to B.

This seems too simplistic, and makes short work of a proof I am working on if it is true. Is something about my logic here incorrect?

Comment: I can't tell what you are talking about, but you should look up Smith Normal Form.

Comment: There are many different types of equivalence. If $A=PB$ as above, then $A,B$ have the same kernel, but the images may differ.